# Calculating the time taken for the process to start up..!

Tags: windows, performance, time, process, launchd

How can i calculate the time taken for the processes to start up in Windows.

Can i use GetProcessTimes() for this..??

```
 BOOL WINAPI GetProcessTimes(HANDLE hProcess,
  LPFILETIME lpCreationTime, LPFILETIME lpExitTime,
 LPFILETIME lpKernelTime,
  LPFILETIME lpUserTime
);
```

We can get the process creation time from that.  Rather cant we get the time taken for a particular process to start up (for example: time taken for notepad.exe to open)

Will it work by subtracting the user time with the kernel time or creation time? Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: You should define what *start up* means exactly. For server programs or command line tools it might not be that easy! Not every program is popping some top-level window!

Comment: The start up time, i mean the duration of a process to load its dependencies and opens to the user.

Comment: What does that mean for a daemon program (or a server like `lighttpd`), or a command line tool (e.g. `grep`) ??

Comment: The operating system does not keep track of when an application" opens to the user". That is something you will need to monitor yourself (e.g., by watching for the window to be created).

Comment: Ya. i can understand that those commands wont pop up any windows. but in the case of other applications that pops up a window.?